# Parsec Parsing list of different kind of statements

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I'm trying to parse (for now) a subset of the Dot language.
The grammar is [here](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html) and my code is the following

```
import System.Environment
import System.IO
import qualified Text.Parsec.Token as P
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Char -- for letter
import Text.Parsec
import qualified Control.Applicative as App

import Lib
type Id = String
data Dot = Undirected Id  Stmts
         | Directed Id  Stmts
         deriving (Show)

data Stmt = NodeStmt Node | EdgeStmt Edges
          deriving (Show)
type Stmts = [Stmt]

data Node = Node Id Attributes deriving (Show)
data Edge =  Edge Id Id deriving (Show)
type Edges = [Edge]

data Attribute = Attribute Id Id deriving (Show)
type Attributes = [Attribute]

dotDef :: P.LanguageDef st
dotDef = P.LanguageDef
  { P.commentStart    = "/*"
  , P.commentEnd      = "*/"
  , P.commentLine     = "//"
  , P.nestedComments  = True
  , P.identStart      = letter
  , P.identLetter     = alphaNum
  , P.reservedNames   = ["node", "edge", "graph", "digraph", "subgraph", "strict" ]
  , P.caseSensitive   = True
  , P.opStart         = oneOf "-="
  , P.opLetter        = oneOf "->"
  , P.reservedOpNames = []
  }



lexer = P.makeTokenParser dotDef

brackets    = P.brackets lexer
braces      = P.braces lexer

identifier  = P.identifier lexer
reserved    = P.reserved lexer

semi = P.semi lexer
comma = P.comma lexer

reservedOp = P.reservedOp lexer

eq_op = reservedOp "="
undir_edge_op = reservedOp "--"
dir_edge_op = reservedOp "->"

edge_op = undir_edge_op <|> dir_edge_op

-- -> Attribute
attribute = do
  id1 <- identifier
  eq_op
  id2 <- identifier
  optional (semi <|> comma)
  return $ Attribute id1 id2

a_list = many attribute

bracked_alist =
  brackets $ option [] a_list

attributes =
  do
    nestedAttributes <- many1 bracked_alist
    return $ concat nestedAttributes


nodeStmt = do
  nodeName <- identifier
  attr <- option [] attributes
  return $ NodeStmt $ Node nodeName attr

dropLast = reverse . tail . reverse

edgeStmt = do
  nodes <- identifier `sepBy1` edge_op
  return $ EdgeStmt $ fmap (\x -> Edge (fst x) (snd x)) (zip (dropLast nodes) (tail nodes))


stmt = do
  x <- nodeStmt <|> edgeStmt
  optional semi
  return x

stmt_list = many stmt
graphDecl = do
  reserved "graph"
  varName <- option "" identifier
  stms <- braces stmt_list
  return $ Undirected varName stms

digraphDecl = do
  reserved "digraph"
  varName <- option "" identifier
  stms <- braces stmt_list
  return $ Directed varName stms

topLevel3 = do
  spaces
  graphDecl <|> digraphDecl

main :: IO ()
main = do
  (file:_) <- getArgs
  content <- readFile file
  case parse topLevel3 "" content of
    Right g -> print g
    Left err -> print err
```

Given this input

```
digraph PZIFOZBO{
        a[toto = bar] b ;   c  ; w  // 1
        a->b // 2
        }
```

It works fine if line 1 or line 2 is commented, but if both are enabled, it fails with

> (line 3, column 10): unexpected "-" expecting identifier or "}"

My understanding it that the parser picks first matching rule (with backtracking). Here both edge and node statement starts with and identifier, so it always pick this one.

I tried reversing the order in `stmt`, without any luck.
I also tried to sprinkle some `try` in stmt, nodeStmt and edgeStmt, without luck either.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that I get the same error whether or not line 1 is commented out, so:

```
digraph PZIFOZBO{
        a->b
        }
```

also says `unexpected "-"`.

As I think you have correctly diagnosed, the problem here is that the `stmt` parser tries `nodeStmt` first.  That succeeds and parses `"a"`, leaving `"->b"` yet to be consumed, but `->b` isn't a valid statement.  Note that Parsec does **not** backtrack automatically in the absence of a `try`, so it's not going to go back and revisit this decisions when it "discovers" that `->b` can't be parsed.

You can "fix" this problem by swapping the order in `stmt`:

```
x <- edgeStmt <|> nodeStmt
```

but now the parse will break on an expression like `a[toto = bar]`.  That's because `edgeStmt` is buggy.  It parses `"a"` as a valid statement `EdgeStmt []` because `sepBy1` allows a single edge `"a"`, which isn't what you want.

If you rewrite `edgeStmt` to require at least one edge:

```
import Control.Monad (guard)
edgeStmt = do
  nodes <- identifier `sepBy1` edge_op
  guard $ length nodes > 1
  return $ EdgeStmt $ fmap (\x -> Edge (fst x) (snd x)) (zip (dropLast nodes) (tail nodes))
```

*and* adjust `stmt` to "`try`" an edge statement first and backtrack to a node statement:

```
stmt = do
  x <- try edgeStmt <|> nodeStmt
  optional semi
  return x
```

then your example compiles fine.

Comment: As an aside, `dropLast` is just the library function `init`, and `zipWith` combines `map` and `zip`, so you can replace that last statement in `edgeStat` with `return $ EdgeStmt $ zipWith Edge (init nodes) (tail nodes)`

Comment: I thought there was something for dropLast, but I couldn't find it, so I wrote my own ^^.

Regarding the original question, first, thank for the great answer. If I wanted to, how could I further extend the parser to deal with te 4th case in stmt (ie   ID '=' ID) ? More try ?

Comment: Yes, I think `x <- try edgeStmt <|> try equalsStmt <|> nodeStmt` ought to work.